# New list item form redirect prompts to download

Tags: list-form, page-viewer-web-part

I created a custom form to add to a list and changed the forms URL to include 
`?source=thankyoupage.aspx` but when a user submits, the user gets prompted to download the page instead of redirecting to the page. My form is in a page viewer web part so maybe that is part of the issue?

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Try `Source` instead of `source`. I believe query strings are Case Sensitive.

Comment: ^ they are not case sensitive :)

Comment: I wondered that too but i tried it anyway and no go. Still tries to download the page =-(